# Rather annoying issue with a Swing combo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

https://youtu.be/8djixdHNoEQ - this video shows what I am facing, in that the `JComboBox` seems to be display multiple times/leaving an after-image.

Here is how I have setup the combo box:

```
private String[] list = { "Inches/Centimeters", "Miles/Kilometres", "Pounds/Kilograms", "Gallons/Litres", "Feet/Metres", "Celcius/Kelvin", "Acres/Hectare" }; //the String array the ComboBox uses

private JComboBox<String> conversionCombo; //defining the JComboBox.
conversionCombo = new JComboBox<String>(list); // creating JComboBox
```

Other than defining the list it uses, the comb box itself and creating the combo box, there is no other code which interacts with this component. (other than the code which sets the Combo box up, and adds it to the screen etc.)

Example program below.

thing1 (driver class, sets up JFrame):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class thing1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Thing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        thing2 thing2 = new thing2();

        frame.getContentPane().add(thing2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

thing2 (sets up UI element - in this case just the JComboBox):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class thing2 extends JPanel {

    /**
     *  Declaring all variables and components to be used within the GUI
     */

    private String[] list = { "Inches/Centimeters", "Miles/Kilometres", "Pounds/Kilograms", "Gallons/Litres", "Feet/Metres", "Celcius/Kelvin", "Acres/Hectare" };



    thing2() {
        JComboBox<String> conversionCombo = new JComboBox<String>(list); // creating JComboBox
        add(conversionCombo);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 80));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

}
```

Should be able to compile this and see the issue. In this case if you are to select anything from the dropdown and move your mouse to the right of the combobox whilst your mouse is 'within' it (ex: https://i.imgur.com/Z2Slrl3.gifv), "after-images" will appear.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"there is no other code which interacts with this component."* (chuckle) it'd be simple if that were the case, but even to lay the combo box out and put it on-screen, it's interacting with, or dependent on, other code (a lot of which is done by the JVM).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I have added an example which is barebones and includes just code relating to the JComboBox in question.

Comment: What I think, is you are having EXCEPTION somewhere that causes artifacts to not be repainted. Moreover it looks like you would either add multiple times the same combobox or you are adding/removing it (probably by mistake) somewhere without revalidating layout - that would look like this.

Comment: @dstlny but does your barebones example reproduce the problem? If it doesn't, we can't help. Note that it violates the swing threading rules, though: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: @JBNizet On my system it does, yeah. I have given steps on how to reproduce below the snippets.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug with the two classes you posted.

Comment: Have updated steps, bug only occurs if you are within the bounds of the ComboBox and move your cursor to the right of it, example also provided.

Comment: Also works fine for me. The code looks perfectly reasonable. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7. I suggest you delete all the class files from your project. You may have garbage lying around. Also, try the demo from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) so you know you have fresh code.

Comment: I can confirm the same as JB Nizet & camickr. Though it uses less than best practices, that code works as expected here, with no visual artifacts no matter what I do. *"bug only occurs if you are within the bounds of the ComboBox and move your cursor to the right of it"* Cursor? I opened the combo and moved the mouse outside and used the right arrow key (not sure what you mean by 'cursor') & saw nothing strange.

Comment: Strange. I'll go ahead and recreate the Project and see if that clears it up then. Weird little bug. Thanks anyway guys, much appreciated. @camickr.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for taking the time to help anyways man, very much appreciated. Appears to be system specific or something, i'll reinstall the JDK and re-import the project.

Comment: *"i'll reinstall the JDK and re-import the project."* Try the suggestion(s) of @camickr first!

Comment: Have done. Demo also had the bug, so probably the issue is system specific. I'll give clean reinstalls to the JDK and if that doesn't solve the issue then reinstall Eclipse. Thanks once again, this one had me scratching my head haha.